# How to Split Column headers into two lines while creating Txt Ouput

Tags: r, rstudio

### I am trying to display following information in the txt outputs with N/% to be displayed in next line.

Var1          Treatment1           Treatment2

### **(N/%)**            **(N/%)**

I have tried using Kableextra, Huxtable, Flextable but I see limitation of getting expected format while outputting in Txt.

Any input will be valuable.

Comment: To be more clear, N/% should be expected under Treatment columns..

Comment: Hi! Do you have any sample data you can include in your question?